# Loop different content imacros

Tags: loops, imacros

I still new in imacros, how to replace with loop for the list of set content

Here my code:

```
SET IMAGE1 C:\1.jpg
SET IMAGE2 C:\2.jpg
SET SEL1    612
SET SEL2    271
.
.
.
.
SET SEL50   602

'if possible the image i want to make random for image1 and image2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ID:formular ATTR=ID:image_0 CONTENT={{IMAGE1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ID:formular ATTR=ID:image_1 CONTENT={{IMAGE2}}
'this line of content will replace SEL1 until SEL50
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:formular ATTR=ID:test CONTENT=%{{SEL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:formular ATTR=ID:c_publish

'currently my code will repeat 50 time
 TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ID:formular ATTR=ID:image_0 CONTENT={{IMAGE1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ID:formular ATTR=ID:image_1 CONTENT={{IMAGE2}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:formular ATTR=ID:test CONTENT=%{{SEL2}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:formular ATTR=ID:c_publish
.
.
.
```

thanks in advance

Comment: "POS=[{{!LOOP}}]" should help

Comment: Hi @Valera, could you explain more how to use that on POS? Thanks

Comment: @user2982040 is there some submit button that needs to be pressed after the values are filled up?

Comment: Hi @user2982040, "The variable {{!LOOP}} represents the current loop number when a script is running in loop mode."
here's a little demo: http://wiki.imacros.net/Demo-Slideshow

Comment: Hi @NarenMurali, yes there have submitted button, updated the code.. sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job, the code can be looped 50 times, it uses a data source called **file_name.csv** so create this and load the values of sel1 to sel50 in the first column. From my understanding of the question I have randomized image1 and image2 to toggle between two images.

***Note:*** don't forget to change the path in line3 to the location of your CSV file.

**CODE *(UPDATED BASED ON NEW REQUIREMENT FROM COMMENTS BELOW)*:**

```
VERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !DATASOURCE "C:/Users/Testing/Desktop/file_name.csv"
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomImage=Math.random() >= 0.5 ? 'C:\1.jpg' : 'C:\2.jpg';randomImage;")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ID:formular ATTR=ID:image_0 CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomImage=Math.random() >= 0.5 ? 'C:\1.jpg' : 'C:\2.jpg';randomImage;")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ID:formular ATTR=ID:image_1 CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomImage=Math.random() >= 0.5 ? 'C:\1.jpg' : 'C:\2.jpg';randomImage;")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ID:formular ATTR=ID:image_2 CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomImage=Math.random() >= 0.5 ? 'C:\1.jpg' : 'C:\2.jpg';randomImage;")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ID:formular ATTR=ID:image_3 CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomImage=Math.random() >= 0.5 ? 'C:\1.jpg' : 'C:\2.jpg';randomImage;")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ID:formular ATTR=ID:image_4 CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomImage=Math.random() >= 0.5 ? 'C:\1.jpg' : 'C:\2.jpg';randomImage;")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ID:formular ATTR=ID:image_5 CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomImage=Math.random() >= 0.5 ? 'C:\1.jpg' : 'C:\2.jpg';randomImage;")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ID:formular ATTR=ID:image_6 CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
'this line of content will replace SEL1 until SEL50
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:formular ATTR=ID:test CONTENT=%{{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:formular ATTR=ID:c_publish
```

**CODE:**

```
VERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !DATASOURCE "C:/Users/Testing/Desktop/file_name.csv"
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomImage=Math.random() >= 0.5 ? 'C:\1.jpg' : 'C:\2.jpg';randomImage;")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ID:formular ATTR=ID:image_0 CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
SET !VAR2 EVAL("var randomImage= Math.random() >= 0.5 ? 'C:\1.jpg' : 'C:\2.jpg';randomImage;")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ID:formular ATTR=ID:image_1 CONTENT={{!VAR2}}
'this line of content will replace SEL1 until SEL50
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:formular ATTR=ID:test CONTENT=%{{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:formular ATTR=ID:c_publish
```

**CSV File(Name: file_name.csv):**

```
202
207
212
217
222
227
232
237
242
247
252
257
262
267
272
277
282
```

Comment: Thanks @NarenMurali, but i still cant get value from csv file, do i miss something here?

Comment: i got it for the path no need to use double quote, directly C:/Users/Testing/Desktop/file_name.csv, 

for the image, if i have 6 image, how to set random for 6 image, let say i have ID:image_1 until image_6

Comment: @user2982040 I edited my answer for your new query, you just add more tags with the respective ATTR=ID values